# How can I get a one line per test result with Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to take test case results from Robot Framework runs and import those results into other tools (ElasticSearch, ALM tools, etc).

Towards that end I would like to be able to generate a text file with one line per test.  Here is an example line pipe delimited:

```
testcase name | time run | duration | status
```

There are other fields I would add but those are the basic ones.  Any help appreciated.  I have been looking at robot.result http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.2/autodoc/robot.result.html but haven't figured it out yet.  If/when I do I will post answer here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

The output.xml file is very easy to parse with normal XML parsing libraries.

Here's a quick example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime

def get_robot_results(filepath):

    results = []
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        xml = ET.parse(f)
        root = xml.getroot()
        if root.tag != "robot":
            raise Exception("expect root tag 'robot', got '%s'" % root.tag)

    for suite_node in root.findall("suite"):
        for test_node in suite_node.findall("test"):
            status_node = test_node.find("status")

            name = test_node.attrib["name"]
            status = status_node.attrib["status"]
            start = status_node.attrib["starttime"]
            end = status_node.attrib["endtime"]
            start_time = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            end_time = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            elapsed = str(end_time-start_time)

            results.append([name, start, elapsed, status])

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = get_robot_results("output.xml")
    for row in results:
        print(" | ".join(row))
```

Answer (score 4):

Bryan is right that it's easy to parse Robot's output.xml using standard XML parsing modules. Alternatively you can use Robot's own result parsing modules and the model you get from it:

```
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, SuiteVisitor


class PrintTestInfo(SuiteVisitor):

    def visit_test(self, test):
        print('{} | {} | {} | {}'.format(test.name, test.starttime,
                                         test.elapsedtime, test.status))


result = ExecutionResult('output.xml')
result.suite.visit(PrintTestInfo())
```

For more details about the APIs used above see http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/.

Comment: Not as simple as the XML parser (only if you don't know how to use robot.api :) but once you do and see how clean and elegant this code is, its simple on the right side of complex. Plus so much easier to extend.